# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpdialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been looking on Stack Overflow and through the WordPress forums to an answer to this issue, but I can't seem to find it. I'll detail the issue, what I've done, and what I know.

We've got two sites, a development environment and a live environment. At this time, both code bases are synced via GitHub and there are no differences in the files (excluding DB credentials in bb-config.php and wp-config.php). Botha are running WP 3.5.2. On the production site, if you go to add or edit a custom post type (Articles, using the standard WP TinyMCE editor) and try to hyperlink something, nothing happens. On the development site, I can add a hyperlink no problem. In the JS console on the production site I see the following errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined load-scripts.php:466
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'powerTip' myscript.js:8
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpdialog'
```

This error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpdialog'` is the one that shows up only after I click the hyperlink button in the post editor. I've checked the source of both sites, and they are the same, minus different subdomains.

I deactivated all plugins, and tried it again. Same issue. Reinstalled WP 3.5.2 manually and automatically, still persists. Tried clearing all caching. Still persists. I can't deactivate the theme, because then custom post type goes away. I've looked to make sure jQuery isn't being referenced twice.

All the reported issues I've seen here and on the WordPress forums have been resolved by deactivating plugins, reinstalling WP, or deactivating the theme. But, those don't work for me (minus the deactivating the theme, which I explained above).

I'm lost on this one, and not being able to add links is a major problem. We can use  in the HTML editor, but the writers aren't going to know to do that, so any help in solving this problem would be wonderful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if jQuery is loaded in  the first place !!

Comment: I've verified, it is indeed being loaded.

Comment: The errors itself means that the scripts were not loaded properly and it could not fine the reference.. Similarly also check for the other files in the `resources` tab of developer tools

Comment: I checked all the files in the resources tab, they both have the same scripts loaded.

Comment: Can you share a live link?

Comment: My guess is that you're loading jQuery in no conflict mode (default in WP), and using `$`...

Comment: @Sergio I mean I can share the site, but the problem is in the WP Admin console, so I don't believe it is going to help you.

Comment: @elclanrs it is being loaded in no conflict mode, but `$` isn't being used

Comment: The call stack trace should give you some info to track down the problem... Go step by step and put breakpoints until you find the culprit.

Comment: @elclanrs can you give me some guidance on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some further investigation, I figured out that a theme file was adding an extra and older jQuery library into the admin interface that threw off the entire site. After removing it, everything started working again!

Answer (score 0):

You are not including your scripts properly hence their methods not available at time of execution.

Comment: What scripts am I supposed to include? This is just TinyMCE?

Comment: We would need to see either a live link or a jsfiddle mock-up in order to tell you that. one common mistake though is to include plug-ins or extensions before including jquery or some other base library.